# AIR application and HTML pass parameter

Tags: php, html, actionscript-3, air

I have an AIR application that is downloaded from a webpage. 
In order to download the application, one must be logged in.
I would like the first time the user opens the application, to be able to acces the userId that was logged in.

Is there any way do pass that information?

Thanks,
Radu

Comment: I've not done this but I believe you can modify the app install badge to pass parameters in, see link: http://archive.davidtucker.net/2008/01/10/air-tip-5-passing-arguments-to-an-application-on-install/

Comment: Hawks, I think this is it. If you post as a reply, I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to modify the AIR install badge and then pass in parameters through the browser invocation event.

http://archive.davidtucker.net/2008/01/10/air-tip-5-passing-arguments-to-an-application-on-install/

Answer (score -1):

To pass parameters to your Air animation use a 'flashvar' param in your html object.

```
<object ...>
       <param name="movie" value="my_animation.swf?random=23887675198100972" />
        <param name="FlashVars" value="value1=x&value2=y" />
        ...
        <embed src="/my_animation.swf" FlashVars="value1=x&value2=y" ...> 
        </embed>
</object>
```

then in your Air application you can get these params values using :

```
Application.application.parameters['value1']
```

Comment: The OP is talking about how to pass parameters to an AIR application, not an embedded swf. Where is this Application class? I can't find any references to it in the docs.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't check Flex, I thought you might have confused it for NativeApplication. Although I can't find an application property or parameters property in that one linked.